# Is multiple cameras views for mjpeg_server possible?

Tags: ros, mjpeg-server, video, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to set up multiple camera views for tele-operation under mjpeg_server. I would like to utilize up to 4 cameras running on one machine simultaneously to be output to one webpage. Or possibly use uvc_camera to run the camera feeds into ros and use rosservice to set which camera outputs to mjpeg_server. Anyone running this type of setup or something similar, any advice would be appreciated. I have also tried using the options under gscam. But it only allows for 2 camera views in the same window and I was not able to get it working either.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50899/is-multiple-cameras-views-for-mjpeg_server-possible?/) by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 458 on 2012-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume a page can display 4 different image streams by including 4 img tags to the appropriate topics, which might look something like: "img src="http://localhost:8080/stream?topic=/robot/cameraN">"

I have not tried this yet for 4 image streams, but it should be easy to test.

---

Originally posted by [odestcj](https://answers.ros.org/users/313/odestcj/) with karma: 123 on 2012-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1